# Access VBA ordering fields

Tags: vba, ms-access, count

I am hoping to get some help for a solution I am working on. I am working in Access and trying to develop VBA module that will go through a table and order fields. I have a table (code_percents)that contains specific codes (in a field called "code") and associated percentiles (in a field called "percent"). I want to populate another field ("order") that orders the percentiles on a per code basis from greatest to smallest. So a 1 will be assigned to the highest percent per code, and so on. I have a short example below to help explain what I'm trying to do.

```
code  percent  order
----  -------  -----
001      0.54      1
001      0.43      2
001      0.02      3
001      0.01      4
002      1.00      1
003      0.75      1
003      0.25      2
```

The codes in the "code" field can have any number of records.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include the existing VBA code you have tried to use to accomplish this task.

Comment: You might also like to mention why you wish to do this, rather than using an SQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub OrderPercentiles()
Dim sql As String
Dim rs  As Recordset
Dim n   As Long
Dim cod As String

    sql = "SELECT * FROM code_percents ORDER BY [code], [percent] DESC"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, DB_OPEN_DYNASET)

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        cod = rs!code
        n = 0
        Do While cod = rs!code
            n = n + 1
            rs.Edit
                rs!Order = n
            rs.Update
            rs.MoveNext
            If rs.EOF Then Exit Do
        Loop
    Loop
    rs.Close

End Sub
```